# Using CF9 ORM for listing pages: HQL or SQL?

Tags: orm, coldfusion

I have an ORM mapping which has:

magazine object
with a many-to-one relationship to a genre
and a one-to-many relationship to issues

I have an admin page which displays a listing of basic magazine info, the magazines genre (looked up from the linked genre object) and the number of issues currently stored.

It all works fine simply using

```
EntityLoad('magazine');
```

...but a glance at the console log shows that it's doing one query for the list of magazines, one query to look up each different genre name, and one query on each magazine to load all issues for that magazine (just to get the count!). As the dataset gets larger, this is going to be a bigger and bigger performance hit.

Of course, traditionally I'd just have a joined SQL query which would return all the data I need in one query. Is there a way of achieving the same in HQL, or would I be better off with a standard SQL query?

I had a look at the HQL "SELECT" syntax, but it's not very user-friendly as it returns queries with specifically-named columns as an array of arrays, which isn't particularly pleasant to work with...

Answer (score 2):

Something that can help with this is using a fetching strategy. Basically, you can give ORM the instruction to grab those related records using a join

You have to set fetch="join" on the one to many relationship.

For more info on this see: 
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSE01EDE03-6E6B-4669-8C54-358460778450.html

Comment: Thanks Terry - there's a lot of options to learn in this ORM malarkey! However, that doesn't seem to quite do the job: looking at the log, this uses a join when loading a single magazine entity, but when loading ALL magazines it still just loads the magazine table in the primary query...

Comment: Hmmm, odd.  Are you using CFDump to check on the objects?  If so, that negates all lazy settings. (Which would result in more db queries.)

Comment: No, not using CFDump. I'm just doing an EntityLoad() and calling no methods on it, and viewing the SQLlog. I've put the code and logs at https://gist.github.com/175d8979e0c7d2c455be if you want to take a look...